# Protection for XML file import to SQL server using sqlbulcopy

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, sqlbulkcopy

I'm importing XML file values to SQL server database using sqlbulcopy. I need to make protection from invalid import.

How to show some kind of message that file import was successfull into database?

sqlbulcopy is inside asp.net button click to send data to SQl.

**.cs**

```
protected void Rezervuoti_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Data.xml"));

        DataTable dtHall = ds.Tables["Hall"];
        DataTable dtGroup = ds.Tables["HallGroup"];
        DataTable dtSeat = ds.Tables["HallSeat"];

        con.Open();

        using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            bc.DestinationTableName = "Hall";
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("HallID", "HallID");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("TicketLimit", "TicketLimit");
            bc.WriteToServer(dtHall);
        }

        using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            bc.DestinationTableName = "HallGroup";
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("HallID", "HallID");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("HallGroupID", "HallGroupID");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("AZ", "AZ");
            bc.WriteToServer(dtGroup);
        }

        using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            bc.DestinationTableName = "HallSeat";
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("HallGroupID", "HallGroupID");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("ShowSeatID", "ShowSeatID");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Color", "Color");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Price", "Price");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("SeatRow", "SeatRow");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("SeatNumber", "SeatNumber");
            bc.ColumnMappings.Add("IsReserved", "IsReserved");
            bc.WriteToServer(dtSeat);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to transfer the XML just *as is* to a Stored Procedure and handle everything there? And your question? Don't really understand... What is "successful"? The classical approach was a transaction handling within a try/catch/finally block...